# Prüfer implies that all finitely generated ideals are cancellation ideals

Tags: ring-theory

I am trying to prove that if a ring is Prüfer (meaning all of its finitely generated ideals are invertible) then all of its finitely generated ideals are cancellation ideals.

I don't really know where to start with that. I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint for that.

Comment: What is your  definition of Prüfer and/or which of the numerous equivalent characterizations do you know?

Comment: as far as i know prüfer means that all  ideals are invertible. i also know that the localization of a prufer in a prime or a maximal ideal are valuation rings.

Comment: It's all *finitely generated* ideals are invertible. But otherwise it's correct. Now, if you have that as definition. It's really not that hard. You can basically forget the context and just show that  invertible implies cancelative (just multiply by the inverse!).  If you include the content of your comment via an [edit] and you let me know I'll reopen the post.

Comment: definition included. thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for the edit.It's open again.